# Get file list from S3 using aws service proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to get files list in a bucket or using some prefix from S3 using AWS service proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS service proxy"?  Please clarify

Comment: @Vorsprung I assume it's a reference to [S3 Service Proxy in AWS API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html).  Probably should have the [tag:aws-api-gateway] tag if so.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot that seems interesting!  Hadn't looked at that before

Comment: @Vorsprung, its AWS API gateway API type AWS service proxy

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that API Gateway service proxy can make any API call to S3 that you could make directly to S3. Looks like the S3 ListObjects API does support prefix filter, so you would just have to duplicate the HTTP request structure in the API Gateway service proxy and provide the execution role for credentials (if the bucket is protected).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html